# percorrer array e inserir quebra de linha jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, loop

Essa aplicação não funciona do jeito esperado.

var storeElements = [];
    var store = [];

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.add_aluno', function () {

    var aside = $(this).parent().parent().children('aside');
    $(this).parent().parent().append('<aside id="inner_form">' + aside.html() + '</aside>');

    aside.each(function () {
        storeElements.unshift($(this));
    });

    for (var i = 4; i < storeElements.length; i += 4) {
        store.push(storeElements[i]);
    }

    if (store.length >= 4) {
        //Aqui preciso inserir quebra de linha a partir do 4º aside gerado, e o proximo é 8 depois 12, etc..
    }
});
```

Assim ele ta inserindo os asides quando chega no 4º ele insere a quebra de linha só que no 6 7 ele insere novamente, nesse caso eu preciso que insira no 4 depois 8 depois 12, etc...

html

```
<form id="boletin_cad" action="env_boletin.php" method="POST">

    <aside id="inner_form">
        <select name="aluno">
            <option value="">Selecione o aluno</option>
            <?php
            $pega_alunos = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM efcol_cadastro WHERE status_conta = ? ORDER BY nome");
            $pega_alunos->execute(array('Ativo'));
            while ($dados_alunos = $pega_alunos->fetch()) {
                echo '<option value="' . $dados_alunos['id'] . '">' . $dados_alunos['nome'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>            
        </select><br />
        <select name="materia">
            <option value="">Selecione a Matéria</option>
            <option value="01">LIBERTAÇÃO I</option>
            <option value="02">REGIÕES DE CATIVEIRO</option>
            <option value="03">H. ESPIRITUAL</option>
            <option value="04">ESQ. JEZABEL</option>
            <option value="05">ABORTO</option>
            <option value="06">ADULTÉRIO</option>
            <option value="07">DIVÓRCIO</option>
            <option value="08">LIB. SEXUAL I</option>
            <option value="09">LIB. SEXUAL II</option>
            <option value="10">INIMIGOS ESPIRITUAIS</option>
        </select><br />
        <legend>
            <span>Ano Letivo</span>
            <input type="text" name="ano" />
        </legend>
        <legend>
            <span>Semestre</span>
            <select name="semestre">
                <option value="1">1º</option>
                <option value="2">2º</option>
            </select></legend><br /><br />
        <legend>
            <span>Média</span>
            <input type="text" name="notas" />
        </legend>
        <legend>
            <span>Faltas</span>
            <input type="text" name="faltas" />
        </legend>
    </aside>
    <div class="botoes">
        <button name="add_media">Cadastrar</button>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_aluno">+ ADD ALUNO +</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: não sei se entendi mas a ideia é mostrar um resultado sorteado ou realmente a cada quatro indices de uma lista dependendo de como seja a resposta pode ser diferente

Comment: ola a ideia é a cada 4 indices mesmo só que um a cada clique.

Comment: o javascript já sabemos como rola poderia adicionar os asides (html). assim ao que da pra entender vc esta adicionando ao array de elementos (A) o próprio item que chama o evento click (referenciando por this) e novamente adicionando a "A"  quando usa push a variavel store neste ponto esta vazia percebes

Comment: ja inseri o html blz nesse caso so preciso gerar 3 asides no 4 quebra a linha, gera 5, 6, 7 no 8 quebra linha...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom o exemplo abaixo esta bem comentado mas ressalto o fato de armazenar os índices adicionando-os ao inicio pois neste exemplo estes índices "armazenados" são retornados pelo método `pop` que retorna e remove o ultimo item do array.

Pela minha falta de abastecer o elemento `select` via `php` criei uma falsa lista de alunos com `javascript` mesmo só para exemplo, ignore-a.
Contudo é esta lista que define o total possível de asides a serem inseridos exeplo:
Se a classe de alunos (retornados do DB) tem 16 alunos este é o número máximo. E assim por diante.

**considerações**
Considere que sua lista de alunos sera servida por `php` então substitua este trecho:

```
// define o número para o loop reverso
var i = listaAluno.length;
```

Por este:

```
// define o número para o loop reverso
var i = $('#inner_form select[name=aluno]').length;
```

Neste exemplo em vez de criar um loop salteado (o que não tava dando certo) simplesmente verifica-se se o índice do item no `array` é múltiplo de quatro usando a expressão `([i][0] % 4 === 0)` más vale notar que um array em `javascript` inicia-se sempre por `0` para uma melhor observação adicionei cores e como a proposta da pergunta elementos `br` e `hr` a cada quatro entradas é isso.

**editado** com jquery

```js
/**
 * como não pude abastecer uma lista de alunos via php este trecho prove
 * uma lista "falsa" simplesmente para criar uma quantia de exemplo (20 alunos)
 */
var listaAluno = [
    {id:1,name:'Ana'},
    {id:2,name:'Paula'},
    {id:3,name:'Analize'},
    {id:4,name:'Moises'},
    {id:5,name:'Aragao'},
    {id:6,name:'Paulo'},
    {id:7,name:'Pedro'},
    {id:8,name:'Joao'},
    {id:9,name:'Carol'},
    {id:10,name:'Atila'},
    {id:11,name:'William'},
    {id:12,name:'Carlos'},
    {id:13,name:'Eduardo'},
    {id:14,name:'Andre'},
    {id:15,name:'Rafael'},
    {id:16,name:'Benito'},
    {id:17,name:'Tavares'},
    {id:18,name:'Belize'},
    {id:19,name:'Andresa'},
    {id:20,name:'Rosangela'}
];
// abastece o select
for(var i=0; i<listaAluno.length; i++){
   $('#inner_form select[name=aluno]').append('<option value="'+listaAluno[i].id+'">'+listaAluno[i].name);
}

// armazene fora do scopo do evento "click" um objeto array
var store = [];

// captura o html do aside
var aside = $('#inner_form').html();

// define o número para o loop reverso
var i = listaAluno.length;

// faz o loop reverso
for (;i--;) {
     // verifica se o indice do item é multiplo de 4
     if([i][0] % 4 === 0){
        // caso seja adiciona br hr etc...
        store.unshift('<aside style="background-color:green;" id="inner_form">' +aside+ '</aside><br><hr><br>');
     }else{
        //caso não seja multiplo de 4 não adiciona br hr etc...
        store.unshift('<aside style="background-color:red;" id="inner_form">' +aside+ '</aside>');
     }
}

// evento de click
$('body').on('click', 'span.add_aluno', function () {
    // verifica se há itens no array (store)
    if (store.length > 0) {
        // retorna e remove o ultimo item do array (store)
        $('#boletin_cad').append(store.pop());
    }
    // quando não houver mais itens não faz nada 
});
```

```html
<form id="boletin_cad" action="env_boletin.php" method="POST">

    <aside id="inner_form">
        <select name="aluno">
            <option value="">Selecione o aluno</option>
            <!--
            <?php
            $pega_alunos = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM efcol_cadastro WHERE status_conta = ? ORDER BY nome");
            $pega_alunos->execute(array('Ativo'));
            while ($dados_alunos = $pega_alunos->fetch()) {
                echo '<option value="' . $dados_alunos['id'] . '">' . $dados_alunos['nome'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
            -->
        </select><br />
        <select name="materia">
            <option value="">Selecione a Matéria</option>
            <option value="01">LIBERTAÇÃO I</option>
            <option value="02">REGIÕES DE CATIVEIRO</option>
            <option value="03">H. ESPIRITUAL</option>
            <option value="04">ESQ. JEZABEL</option>
            <option value="05">ABORTO</option>
            <option value="06">ADULTÉRIO</option>
            <option value="07">DIVÓRCIO</option>
            <option value="08">LIB. SEXUAL I</option>
            <option value="09">LIB. SEXUAL II</option>
            <option value="10">INIMIGOS ESPIRITUAIS</option>
        </select><br />
        <legend>
            <span>Ano Letivo</span>
            <input type="text" name="ano" />
        </legend>
        <legend>
            <span>Semestre</span>
            <select name="semestre">
                <option value="1">1º</option>
                <option value="2">2º</option>
            </select></legend><br /><br />
        <legend>
            <span>Média</span>
            <input type="text" name="notas" />
        </legend>
        <legend>
            <span>Faltas</span>
            <input type="text" name="faltas" />
        </legend>
    </aside>
    <div class="botoes">
        <button name="add_media">Cadastrar</button>
        <span style="cursor:pointer;" class="add_aluno">+ ADD ALUNO +</span>
    </div>

</form>







<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**editado**
Com respeito aos usuários que já lerão esta resposta vou manter a resposta original para que não se percam nos comentários feitos com base nela.

```js
// pre defina uma variavel para receber um objeto(array)
var store = [];

// assumindo que este indice ve de algum lugar (um db por exemplo)
var contarAside = new Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);

// faça o loop para arazenar os resultados
for (var i = 4; i < contarAside.length; i += 4) {
     // adicione ao inicio
     store.unshift(contarAside[i]);
}

// mostrar resultados
var view = document.getElementById('display');

// capture o botão
var btn = document.getElementById('init');

// adicione o evento
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(store.length > 0){
       view.innerHTML = "indice: "+store.pop();
    }else{
       view.innerHTML = "acabou";
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="init">Clicar</button><br><br>

<div id="display" style="width:400px;height:200px;padding:1%;"></div>
```

Comment: ola eu adaptei o seu codigo, como pode ver o titulo do post eu quero inserir uma quebra de linha apos os "Asides" que são gerados dinamicamente ao clicar, só que eu quero inserir a quebra de linha somente depois do "Asides" 4, 8, 12, etc...

Comment: codigo novo
    $('body').on('click', 'a.add_aluno', function () {
        var aside = $(this).parent().parent().children('aside');
        $(this).parent().parent().append('<aside id="inner_form">' + aside.html() + '</aside>');
        var store = [];
        aside.each(function () {
            store.push($(this).html());
        });
        for (var i = 4; i < store.length; i += 4) {
            store.unshift(store[i]);
        }
        if (store.length > 0) {
            store.pop().append('<br /><hr /><br />');
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

Comment: Bom se ajudou blz..

Comment: Na verdade ele está adicionando em todos eu quero adicionar à partir do 4 depois 8 depois 12 e assim por diante, tem alguma coisa boba faltando.

Comment: Bem eu não entendi a logica que você usou neste código que colocou aqui nos comentários mas creio que deveria inicialmente armazenar os resultados (de 4 em 4) depois buscar quando houver um evento "click" não executar tudo no evento.  E para armazenar segue esta lógica "store.unshift(contarAside[i]+'<br>');"

Comment: eu adaptei seu codigo para jquery eu crio um vetor de asides e daí faço a requisição para inserir uma quebra de linha apos de 4 em 4 asides, mas assim está inserindo em todos, não estou conseguindo.

Comment: ta acho que saquei... os arrays devem estar fora do scopo do evento click.. veja este print e diga se isto resolve https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh0qg.png

Comment: note que: um dos loops deve armazenar na ordem inversa pois a função pop do array retorna e remove o ultimo item do array, assim se não for vai trazer o resultado inverso.

Comment: nossa segui sua logica so que agora ta inserindo em todos desde o primeiro e eu preciso que insira a partir do 4 depois 8 ...

Comment: hum... não considero minha lógica errada ela busca de 4 em 4 itens do arra "A" e inseri no array "B" que por sua vez é usado no evento click para exibir os itens desse array (B) ao mesmo passo que os apaga para não conflitar com o próximo evento. o exemplo em minha resposta ta funcional

Comment: considere editar sua pergunta (o código nela) adicionando uma parte mais substancial do que usa. isso não significa expor todo o código mas somente o exssencial assim talvez possamos chegar a um resultado

Comment: atualizei a pergunta se puder me ajudar to no aguardo.

Comment: desculpas pela falta de informação inserir o cod html.

Comment: Mano nem sei como te agradecer é isso mesmo que preciso, resolveu meu problema, estava acostumado a usar de outras formas muito obrigado mesmo